# How can I convert a .json list of each individual RGB values into PNG with Python2 PIL?

Tags: python, json, list, python-imaging-library

My list contains values such as this..

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [2, 0, 1], [3, 1, 2], [6, 3, 5], [9, 6, 8], [12, 9, 11], [13, 9, 12], [13, 10, 13], [13, 10, 14], [13, 11, 14], [13, 11, 15], [12, 11, 15]]
```

for example..

How can I cycle through them and look at each RGB value, and then output each of them into a PNG in Python?

```
import json

with open('average.json') as json_data:
    d = json.load(json_data)
    print(d)
```

I have managed to do this so far. Do I add while loop? or for loop?

**SOLUTION BY @DIEGO:**

```
from PIL import Image
import json

with open('average.json') as json_data:
    d = json.load(json_data)

OUTPUT_IMAGE_SIZE = (1280, 720)

# Then we iterate over the color (and the frame numbers, that's the role of enumerate)
for frame_number, color in enumerate(d):
    # PIL wants tuples for colors, not lists
    color = tuple(color)
    # we create a new RGB image with a default color, ie. the full image will be the color we want
    image = Image.new('RGB', OUTPUT_IMAGE_SIZE, color=color)
    # we save it 
    image.save(str(frame_number) + '.png')
```

Comment: How will you know what the dimensions of the image are? Is your example 1x26, 2x13, 13x2 or 26x1 ?

Comment: Hey Rob,

It is a data combination of the dominant rgb color of each frame of a 24fps video that I have extracted. But now, I would like to take this dominant colour in each frame, into an image (1280 * 720) itself.

To put it simpler in another way, I am looking at each pixel of an image, and then scaling it up to become a separate image itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Edited because of last @Ico comment

One way to manipulate images in python is with the [PIL](https://python-pillow.org/) module

```
from PIL import Image

d = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [2, 0, 1], [3, 1, 2], [6, 3, 5], [9, 6, 8], [12, 9, 11],
     [13, 9, 12], [13, 10, 13], [13, 10, 14], [13, 11, 14], [13, 11, 15], [12, 11, 15]]

OUTPUT_IMAGE_SIZE = (1280, 72)

# Then we iterate over the color (and the frame numbers, that's the role of enumerate)
for frame_number, color in enumerate(d):
    # PIL wants tuples for colors, not lists
    color = tuple(color)
    # we create a new RGB image with a default color, ie. the full image will be the color we want
    image = Image.new('RGB', (len(d), 1), color=color)
    # we save it 
    image.save(str(frame_number) + '.png')
```

Comments are self explanatory.
So you will then have all the images of the average color saved as *[numframe].png*

Maybe you should edit your question, it wasn't very clear ! :)

Comment: It's more *solution* than *update* I think.    

If this was what you wanted, you can accept my answer :)